# Why does Apache's mod-rewrite module process some GET requests and not process others?

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get mod_rewrite working. I'm experimenting with a very simple rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/one /var/www/html/oldindex.html
```

Here is the complete config file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/govmeeting.org.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName govmeeting.org
ServerAlias www.govmeeting.org
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
LogLevel trace6 rewrite_module:trace8
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/one /var/www/html/oldindex.html
</VirtualHost>
```

I send two requests from the browser for "govmeeting.org/one". "oldindex.html" exists in my DocumentRoot. I see no processing occurring for either in error.log.

However, at about the same time, an external request arrived from someone else. That request DOES get processed, but not mine. Below is the error.log and access.log for this time period. Note that the GET at 23:05:45 and 23:07:04 for "/one" is NOT processed. But the GET at 23:07:06 for "//wp-config.php" is processed.

I have: Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server built: 2021-10-14T16:24:43. The server is running on a VM in Google Compute Engine.

```
116.179.32.156 - - [05/Dec/2021:22:41:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8945 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36"
67.80.142.21 - - [05/Dec/2021:23:05:45 +0000] "GET /one HTTP/1.1" 404 5729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
67.80.142.21 - - [05/Dec/2021:23:06:05 +0000] "-" 408 5213 "-" "-"
67.80.142.21 - - [05/Dec/2021:23:07:04 +0000] "GET /one HTTP/1.1" 404 1079 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
136.144.41.231 - - [05/Dec/2021:23:07:06 +0000] "GET //wp-config.php HTTP/1.1" 404 493 "-" "Mozlila/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G892A Bulid/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/60.0.3112.107 Moblie Safari/537.36"
67.80.142.21 - - [05/Dec/2021:23:07:24 +0000] "-" 408 563 "-" "-"
209.17.97.34 - - [05/Dec/2021:23:11:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Nimbostratus-Bot/v1.3.2; http://cloudsystemnetworks.com)"
```

Here is the part of error.log for that time period:

```
[Sun Dec 05 23:04:26.847532 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17645] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 05 23:04:26.847605 2021] [core:notice] [pid 17645] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213591 2021] [core:trace5] [pid 17650] protocol.c(708): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] Request received from client: GET //wp-config.php HTTP/1.1
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213740 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_request.c(436): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] Headers received from client:
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213747 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_request.c(439): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Host: govmeeting.org
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213751 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_request.c(439): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   User-Agent: Mozlila/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G892A Bulid/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/60.0.3112.107 Moblie Safari/537.36
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213755 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_request.c(439): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213759 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_request.c(439): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213763 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_request.c(439): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Connection: keep-alive
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213766 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_request.c(439): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Cache-Control: max-age=0
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213770 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_request.c(439): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213773 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_request.c(439): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213803 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 17650] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] 136.144.41.231 - - [govmeeting.org/sid#7fafa63c3810][rid#7fafa64820a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /wp-config.php
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213809 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17650] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] 136.144.41.231 - - [govmeeting.org/sid#7fafa63c3810][rid#7fafa64820a0/initial] applying pattern '^/one' to uri '/wp-config.php'
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213821 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 17650] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] 136.144.41.231 - - [govmeeting.org/sid#7fafa63c3810][rid#7fafa64820a0/initial] pass through /wp-config.php
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213922 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17650] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213929 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17650] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.213933 2021] [core:trace3] [pid 17650] request.c(310): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /wp-config.php
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.214003 2021] [php7:error] [pid 17650] [client 136.144.41.231:35566] script '/var/www/html/wp-config.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.214051 2021] [http:trace3] [pid 17650] http_filters.c(1125): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] Response sent with status 404, headers:
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.214070 2021] [http:trace5] [pid 17650] http_filters.c(1134): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Date: Sun, 05 Dec 2021 23:07:06 GMT
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.214074 2021] [http:trace5] [pid 17650] http_filters.c(1137): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.214077 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_filters.c(955): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Content-Length: 276
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.214084 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_filters.c(955): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.214087 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_filters.c(955): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Connection: Keep-Alive
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.214090 2021] [http:trace4] [pid 17650] http_filters.c(955): [client 136.144.41.231:35566]   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.214111 2021] [core:trace6] [pid 17650] core_filters.c(519): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] will flush because of FLUSH bucket
[Sun Dec 05 23:07:06.313890 2021] [core:trace6] [pid 17650] core_filters.c(519): [client 136.144.41.231:35566] will flush because of FLUSH bucket
```

Comment: I added the complete config file to the post.

Comment: Are there rewrite rules in `/var/www/html/.htaccess` (if it exists)?

Comment: The rewrite rules are in govmeeting.org.conf, as shown above. It is recommended to use the .conf file instead of .htaccess, because those in .htaccess reprocessed on every request.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure there weren't others

Comment: http (containing your rewrite rules) and https (which doesn't)?

Comment: I had rewrite rules in govmeeting.org.conf to redirect http traffic to https. Those rules worked ok . I commented them out for now to make it easier to debug why the other rewrite rules are not working.

Comment: Do both http and https write to the same log files? If so that'll be why some requests are seen to work with your rules but some so not

Comment: Thanks! Your are exactly right. I see both http & https calls in access.log, but only http in error.log. I'm now trying to figure out how get the https error log messages.

Comment: Use ErrorLog etc. directives for the vHost handling https

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132276/discussion-between-john-pankowicz-and-roaima).